# How to make a single nav arrow appear when hovering over half an image in lightbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement navigation arrows as they work in this ekko-lightbox [gallery example](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery) - they appear on the right and left only when the mouse is hovering over just the right or left side of the image. I've been combing through the scripts in Developer Tools and still can't deduce how it's done (I'm pretty new to css). I have the arrows on my site appearing on hover, but I would like to use this more subtle approach of having only one at a time appear depending on which side of the image you're on.

Ekko lightbox is based on Bootstrap's modals, so perhaps there is a way in CSS to do something like this(?):

```
.modal-content(width: 50%):hover .arrow-left {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You can simply use 2 transaperent elements that will take 50%/50%. This is what is done in the link you gave. 2 **a** tag taking half each other

Comment: @Temani Afif  yep that's literally all the example does, two 50% width <a> elements, one on the left, one on the right.

Comment: they are also using flex which make it more funny ;) btw i suggest to remove the question before getting a lot of downvotes as it's off topic

Comment: @TemaniAfif - How can I improve the question? It seemed on topic

Comment: the website is intend to have coding question which mean you need to provide code and hightlight an issue where we can help you. Actually you are simply asking us to tell "how it's done" and "how it can be done" which is off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you create elements that cover the area you want control the hover then use display or something like opacity on hover to adjust.  here is an simple example

```css
.lightBox {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.navHolder {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.navHolder:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightBox">
  <div class="navHolder">
    <span>arrow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="navHolder">
    <span>arrow</span>
  </div>
</div>
```